# Role of callback passed to the individual tasks in the Async library

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

[image: As can be seen from the image the iteratee function has callback in its singnature]

my doubt is what is its role in the function. I run the program with custom cb defined in the iteratee function but that cb ran only once. Please explain

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post an example of how you're calling that?

Comment: 'async.eachSeries(links, (link, callback) => {
    spider(link, nesting - 1, function(){console.log(23)});
  }, callback);
}'

Comment: I know that function(){console.log(23)} isn't a callback but I'm getting the results and this function is being called only once.

Comment: That is the main point of the function, you run all the `iteratee` in parallel and when they all finish (by invoking their callbacks) the callback function (3rd parameter for .each) gets invoked, so you can do anything that is dependent on the collection.